# Replace datatable viewstate manipulation with update panel by JQuery?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-2.0

I have a situation where

> - User can enter multiple prices for an item
> - All data is kept in datatable or datasets inside viewstate until the
>     form is saved
> - All add/update/deletes are performed in viewstate again
> - Griviews are placed inside update panels to show these operations

Problem I am having right now is that my webforms have gone really slow due to many update panels on the page, page size is touching about 800 KB due to all viewstate information.

1. Is there a way I can replace the updatepanel and gridviews altogether with a different approach ?
2. How can I replace current situation with
   JQuery ?
3. What would be the implementation steps (not code just steps) to setup my current task with JQuery ?

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn't use [ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx) for that. Consider storing your `DataTables` and `DataSets` in [session state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx) instead.

Comment: thanks for the reply & helpful Frederic. Why do you recommend session over Viewstate ? Also, can this be done using JQuery and JSON without  session/Viewstate ?

Comment: @Popo, `ViewState` is included in every page sent to the client, then posted back by the client with every request. That can be a huge bandwidth hog, and in your case the client doesn't care about all adds/updates/deletes, it just needs to know what to render for the current request. That's why I recommended session state instead, which remains on the server.

Comment: @Popo, concerning your second question, you can probably do that with jQuery/JSON, but you will have to persist the information on the server anyway. Since HTTP is stateless, you might end up only reimplementing session state yourself...

Comment: It makes more sense to me now. Thank you Fred ! =) One thing, what would we use the Viewstate for anyway when storing at server is a better option instead ?

Comment: @Popo, because Microsoft thought their web controls would be easier to use if they "remembered" modifications to their properties across postbacks. For instance, if you hide a `TextBox` by setting its `Visible` property to `false`, and `ViewState` is enabled, it will stay hidden on subsequent postbacks.

Comment: I always thought Viewstate as a memory for storing data that is meant for that page only. Thanks for the clarification.